# JavaScript/Jquery not executing my functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a basic image rotate. I have my images  stored locally by name in a folder called comics. each comic name is comic_(plus the number). It wont do anything when I click my buttons. It wont even disable my previous button. Please help. Thank you guys.

Here is my JS/Jquery...

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //declare my variables
      var comic_img = $('#comicpane').find('img')
      var current_comic_number = parseInt(comic_img.attr('class').replace('comic_','')) 
      var prev_comic = current_comic_number - 1;
      var next_comic = current_comic_number + 1;    

    });

    if (current_comic_number == 1){

      //disable the prev button
      $("#prev").attr('disabled','disabled');

      //When the user clicks on a nav item
      $(".nav_link").on('click')function(){

        //Get the button they clicked
        current_button = $(This);

        if (current_button.attr('id')) == 'next'
        {
          comic_img.attr('class','comic_') + next_comic + ".jpg";
          comic_img.attr('src','comics/comic_1') + next_comic;

          //change variables to reflect current comic
          current_comic_number +=1;
          next_comic +=1;
          prev_comic +=1;
        }

        //Only other option
        else
        {
          comic_img.attr('src','comics/comic_1') + prev_comic + '.jpg';
          comic_img.attr('class','comic_') + prev_comic;

          //Change variables to reflect comic
          current_comic_number -=1;
          next_comic -=1;
          prev_comic -=1;
        }

        //If comic number is less or equal to 1 and prev button is Not disabled, it needs   to be disabled.
        if (current_comic_number <=1 && !$('#pev').attr('disabled','disabled'))
        {
          $('#prev').removeAttr('disabled')
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Here is my HTML...

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>SRS Comic Zone</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="srscomiczone.css" media="screen">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="header">
    <img id="header" src="HeaderPicture.png" align=center>
    </div>
    <div class="comiczone" id="comicpane" align=center>
    <img class="comic_1" src="comics/comic_1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="comicNav" align=center>
    <button id="prev" class="nav_link">Previous</button>
    <button id="next" class="nav_link" >Next</button>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: where is the script located... your html is not including them

Comment: Its all in one folder(well the comics are in a sub folder named comics which is why my src is comics/comic_

Answer (score 2):

few mistakes,

1) this is how you call a click event

```
$(".nav_link").on('click',function(){ 
  ....
```

and not

```
$(".nav_link").on('click')function(){  //replace this with above code
```

you might also need to delegate your selector if it is added dynamically.....

2)

```
current_button = $(This);
```

should be

```
 current_button = $(this);
```

3) also, notice..if you are using jquery 1.6+, use prop() instead  of attr()

```
$("#prev").prop('disabled',true);
```

instead of

```
$("#prev").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

4) add all your codes inside document.ready `$(document).ready(function(){ //here });` function and not outside.

5) most important, you either have to include the script (js file) inside you html page. or paste all your script codes inside `<head>` tag of your HTML file

Comment: Also point out that his if conditional is wrong.  He's not *checking* if the attribute is disabled, he is *setting* it to disabled and it will always evaluate as 'truthy'.  and He shouldn't use `.removeAttr('disabled')` to take off the disabled, he should use `prop` as you mentioned.

Comment: There's so much wrong.  Also `comic_img.attr('class','comic_') + next_comic + ".jpg";` - He's doing this string concatenation incorrectly?  The concat should take place within the method call I would imagine.

Comment: oppps. thanks... i guess i need to change `few` to `many` ... :).. anyways cheers... its better i delete my answer then pointing out the mistakes.. since there are too many... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trashy. Better use tool like [JS Hint](http://www.jshint.com/) (or other JS validator, or even Chrome/Firefox with web console) to actually make sure code can even run.

Here are (some) of the issues with it:

1. you're missing semicolons
2. your `.ready()` function is (as I believe) ending prematurely
3. you're doing `click` handling wrong (pointed out by @bipen)
4. your `if` statements are messed up
5. you (probably) haven't included scripts into the HTML document

**Ad 1**
Missing semicolon here:

```
var comic_img = $('#comicpane').find('img')
```

**Ad 2**
`current_comic_number` is a local variable in `$.ready()`, but it's used outside of this function

**Ad 3**
It's not valid JS (see @bipen's answer):

```
$(".nav_link").on('click')function(){
```

**Ad 4**
It's not valid `if` statement:

```
if (current_button.attr('id')) == 'next'
```

it should be:

```
if (current_button.attr('id') === 'next')
```

**Ad 5**
Use `<script>` tag only inside `*.html` file, not in `*.js`. On example:

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Then, put all of your JS code into `main.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

Also this stuff should be wrapped by:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav_link").on('click',function(){
    ...
});
```

not just your `var` declarations.